# More than one serialization for a model - what is the conventional approach?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, conventions

Every Laravel/Eloquent model has a `->toArray()` method, [serializing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-serialization) all model attributes (except the ones specified via the `protected $hidden` array) and some of it's related models into a neat array, or into JSON via the `->toJson()`.

Suppose I have a model that has a lot of attributes and relations, like this:

```
class Article extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $with = ['comments'];
    // probably also have several kilobytes of data in the text attribute

    ...

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
};
```

This model is usually retrieved and displayed via its serialized form, but in two different ways:

1. A single `Article` for user viewing and commenting. This would need to contain the full article content and all its comments. It might or might not make sense to serialize the comments separately instead of including them with a `$with`.
2. A list of articles, maybe corresponding to a certain topic or search request, for the user to pick an article for viewing. In this case, no text and no comments should be included, so the payload would be minimized.

What's the conventional approach to go about this? For example, do you create an alternative serialization method (e.g., `->toShortJson()` or `->toLongJson()` with a more sensible naming)? If so, is it conventional to minimize serialized models, or to make them as inclusive as possible? And does this not go against the Laravel philosophy somehow?